# Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's respond_to?

Tags: python, ruby, class

Is a way to see if a class responds to a method in Python? like in ruby:

```
class Fun
  def hello
    puts 'Hello'
  end
end

fun = Fun.new
puts fun.respond_to? 'hello' # true
```

Also is there a way to see how many arguments the method requires?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hmmm .... I'd think that `hasattr` and `callable` would be the easiest way to accomplish the same goal:

```
class Fun:
    def hello(self):
        print 'Hello'

hasattr(Fun, 'hello')   # -> True
callable(Fun.hello)     # -> True
```

You could, of course, call `callable(Fun.hello)` from within an exception handling suite:

```
try:
    callable(Fun.goodbye)
except AttributeError, e:
    return False
```

As for introspection on the number of required arguments; I think that would be of dubious value to the language (even if it existed in Python) because that would tell you nothing about the required semantics.  Given both the ease with which one can define optional/defaulted arguments and variable argument functions and methods in Python it seems that knowing the "required" number of arguments for a function would be of very little value (from a programmatic/introspective perspective).

Comment: thanks, Is there are way to use `callable` with the method name as a string?

Comment: yurib shows an example of using getattr() with an instance and the name of the attribute (as a string) and then calling callable() on that:  callable(getattr(Fun(), 'hello'))

Comment: @error: `callable(getattr(Fun, "hello", None))`. The third argument to `getattr` is a default value if the object doesn't have said attribute.

Comment: @katrielalex: Yes, specifying the default return vallue is much better.  On a separate note, it seems odd that you can call the gettattr directly on the class (rather than an instance of the class as I was doing).  It also seems like that could, conceivably, fail for some strange case where some class was dynamically generating some of its methods/attributes (in __new__ or __init__).   Calling on an instance seems like it should be preferable to calling on the class directly).

Comment: @Jim: true, although it's not very common to have to generate instance _methods_ in `__init__`. Depends on the use case.

Comment: @Katrielalex: Even if it's uncommon it's better to have your code implement semantics that are as close to your intentions as is reasonable.  If someone later changes the implementation of the class you're coding against then the code which is checking an instance of it will continue to work while one which was checking the class by its earlier implementation would suddenly fail.

Answer (score 8):

Has method:

```
func = getattr(Fun, "hello", None)
if callable(func):
  ...
```

Arity:

```
import inspect
args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(Fun.hello)
arity = len(args)
```

Note that arity can be pretty much anything if you have `varargs` and/or `varkw` not None.

Answer (score 2):

`dir(instance)` returns a list of an objects attributes.
`getattr(instance,"attr")` returns an object's attribute.
`callable(x)` returns True if x is callable.

```
class Fun(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "Hello"

f = Fun()
callable(getattr(f,'hello'))
```

Comment: As others pointed out, you should use hasattr() to check for the existence of an attribute.

Comment: `hasattr()` does not tell if the attribute is a method (ie callable).

Comment: this will raise an exception if the class doesn't have an attribute `"hello"`, which is probably not what is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I am no Ruby expert, so I am not sure if this answers your question. I think you want to check if an object contains a method. There are numerous ways to do so. You can try to use the `hasattr()` function, to see if an object hast the method:

```
hasattr(fun, "hello") #True
```

Or you can follow the python guideline **don't ask to ask, just ask** so, just catch the exception thrown when the object doesn't have the method:

```
try:
    fun.hello2()
except AttributeError:
    print("fun does not have the attribute hello2")
```

Comment: ooops, of course you are right, I got mixed up with C++. Edited.

Comment: And advantage of attempting the call wrapped with an exception handler is that you can try the desired semantics and test the result ... which is much better, in most cases, than attempting to introspect *and then* having to be prepared for semantic mismatches when you try to call anyway.

Comment: 6-year-late comment alert: the problem with the second one is that you're using exceptions as flow control and if you're looping over a bunch of objects that may or may not respond to a method, you're going to throw a lot of errors

Comment: Ack on discouraging using exceptions for control flow